# not load my website on facebook

Tags: html, regex, facebook, samplegrabber

sample link is : http://upfrontnews.us/news.php?id=24

when i put this link on facebook
facebook not load this content for link and load other content
i think this problem is about html

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the image, the title and the description of your article does not load into the Facebook when you add the link.

This can be fixed by doing the following:

1. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
2. Paste your non-working link.
3. Click '**Scrape Again**' button

Comment: @user3312995 I am happy that this answer helped you out. If you want, you can mark it as accepted answer so that other people can find it helpful in case they have a similar issue.